# Creating proxy using servlet or sockets

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, proxy

I need to create proxy that needs to be installed locally as windows32(64) service and should run automatically when operating system run. It should route requests to particular server or to the original server depending on some criteria. Also should keep track of user session and cookies. Should I go with servlet api and Tomcat OR run my own server and do socket programming?

Comment: why not use already available apache for proxy/reverse-proxy?

Comment: Do you mean on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html ?